# set webbrowser value + windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, browser, windows-phone-8

I have a html in my property Description. When I bind this property with a textblock (ex texthide), it shows the html in textblock. But I can't bind the WebBrowser with this property. How can I bind html string to WebBrowser?

```
<ScrollViewer 
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
  Margin="25, 0, 0, 0" 
  Grid.Row="0">

  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <TextBlock 
      x:Name="TextHide"  
      Text="{Binding Path=Descrption}" 
      Style="{StaticResource servicesText}" 
      TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <phone:WebBrowser 
      Source="{Binding Descrption}" 
      x:Name="webBrowserHTML" 
      Foreground="Black" 
      Loaded="webBrowserHTML_Loaded" />

<!--<Image Source="../Images/cont_banner.png" Width="270"  Grid.Row="1"/>-->

    <Button Grid.Row="1">
      <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/cont_banner.png" />
      </Button.Background>
      <Button.Content>
        <HyperlinkButton Content="" NavigateUri="callto:3950" />
      </Button.Content>
    </Button>

  </StackPanel>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Any ideas please?
Best regards

Answer (score 5):

In order to be able to bind HTML directly to the `WebBrowser` control, you have to create an attached property:

```
namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    public static class WebBrowserHelper
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HtmlProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Html", typeof(string), typeof(WebBrowserHelper), new PropertyMetadata(OnHtmlChanged));

        public static string GetHtml(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
        {
            return (string)dependencyObject.GetValue(HtmlProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHtml(DependencyObject dependencyObject, string value)
        {
            dependencyObject.SetValue(HtmlProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnHtmlChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var browser = d as WebBrowser;

            if (browser == null)
                return;

            var html = e.NewValue.ToString();

            browser.NavigateToString(html);
        }
    }
}
```

Add the required XAML Namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:cxi="clr-namespace:YourAppNamespace"
```

And use it like this:

```
<phone:WebBrowser cxi:WebBrowserHelper.Html="{Binding Question.Body}" />
```

[Source](http://compiledexperience.com/blog/posts/binding-html-to-the-web-browser-control)